# Enable Button during certain day & time

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to enable a button ONLY during 5PM to 10PM every day, except Monday.
When the button is disabled, `<p></p>` should show up (like a notification to the visitor why it is disabled.)

I did try to write the JavaScript on my own, but it seem not to work correctly. I don't know anything about that language and did the script with aid of different sites.

Here is my script:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktimer" value="Check"/>
<p id=timer style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
            <!-- 
            var enableDisable = function(){
                var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
                var day = new Date().getDay();
                if (day == 1){
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'block';
                }
                else{
                if (UTC_hours > 16 && UTC_hours < 22){
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'block';
                }
                }
            };
            setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
            enableDisable();
            // -->
            </script>
```

Comment: Unless you don't care if your clients do things like change their clock to get around your limiting of the button, you will need to enforce this limit server side.

Comment: @crush Even if they change their clock, it won't be of any benefit :)

Comment: And why is that? Why disable it at all then?

Comment: @user3174114 it doesn't matter. This isn't something you leave to client-side code.

Comment: @user3174114 You should store your `#checktimer` and `#timer` nodes as variables, instead of using `getElementById` every time.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo Im trying to disable the button as simple as possible.. I am not really experienced in html/php/javascript stuff. To disable the button in this way is acceptable for me. I am just wondering why it doesn't work^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fYg7/1/)

Try setting the attribute on the element, instead of a property on the element object:

```
document.getElementById('checktimer').setAttribute('disabled');
```

To remove it, use

```
document.getElementById('checktimer').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

As others have mentioned, you should cache the `checktimer` element in a variable, instead of looking it up each time.

A couple of other minor things I changed:

- Removed those Javascript comment things you had. You don't need those.
- Added quotes around the value of the `id` attribute for your `p` element.

Comment: if (UTC_hours > 16 && UTC_hours < 22) {
            document.getElementById('checktimer').setAttribute('disabled');
            document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';

I want the button to be enabled when its 5pm - 10pm, setting the attribute = disabled makes my wish not come true does it?

I don't know how to cache a checktimer, but thanks for your advices.

Comment: @HViet Did you visit the DEMO link at the top of my answer? It works for me. Whether the time frame is the time frame you want to target is not my problem. I used the parameters you gave.

Comment: In my script during 5pm - 10pm it says disable = false, in your script it says setAttribute('disabled') which is like disable = true, right?

Comment: @HViet Yes. I guess I switched them. Go ahead and switch them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
var enableDisable = function(){                    
    var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours(); //Don't add 1 here       
    var day = new Date().getUTCDay();  //Use UTC here also

    if (day != 1 && UTC_hours >= 17 && UTC_hours < 22){
        document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'block';
    }
};

setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
```

Cheers

Comment: im adding 1 because im living in GMT +1 (or does it mean somethin else?)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you shouldn't enable or disable the button based on JavaScript DateTime because it gets the client machine's date, meaning that if the user changes it's system date the button will be enabled. You should verify it on the server-side code, such as PHP or ASP. There, you can check for datetime validation, and write the button on the page, or not.

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote. It's a valid point, and should be considered.

Comment: OP gets UTC time, so changing clock does not affect the functioning of that script. This post doesn't answer the question and doesn't help to get script working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the Date() class itself on javascript refers to the local system date time. Changing the clock indeed changes the behaviour of the script.
And, you're right. I didn't answer the question, I'm sorry. I'm new here, and tougth that we should answer in a way that not only give the imediate solution, but also points the OP to the best direciton. Obviously, I was wrong.

Comment: As @LcSalazar has mentioned, the UTC date is an offset of the current local system time. So yes, it will be affected. Regardless, this answer doesn't deserve a down vote - nor does it deserve an up vote.

Answer (score -1):

Just get rid of the HTML comment `<!--` or comment it with `//`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //<!-- 
            var enableDisable = function(){
                var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
                var day = new Date().getDay();
                if (day == 1){
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'block';
                }
                else{
                if (UTC_hours > 16 && UTC_hours < 22){
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('checktimer').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'block';
                }
                }
            };
            setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
            enableDisable();
            // -->
            </script>
```

Your script should then work normally