# How to create button which get enabled on specific date and time like flipkart sale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i like to create a button like which we can see in flipkart sale which can be clickable on specific date and time.

i can disable for specific time using this code.

**Button :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="myTimer"></div>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btnDisable" disabled onclick="alert('Finally!')">Please wait...</button>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#wrapper {
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #7F7F7F;
  width:150px;
  margin:25px auto;
  padding:25px;
  background-color:#E3E4E4;
}

#myTimer {
  font:64px Tahoma bold;
  padding:20px;
  display:block;
}

button {
  width:125px;
  padding:10px;
}

.btnEnable {
  background-color:#E6F9D2;
  border:1px solid #97DE4C;
  color:#232323;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.btnDisable {
  background-color:#FCBABA;
  border:1px solid #DD3939;
  color:#232323;
  cursor:wait;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
var sec = 15;
var myTimer = document.getElementById('myTimer');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
window.onload = countDown;

function countDown() {
  if (sec < 10) {
    myTimer.innerHTML = "0" + sec;
  } else {
    myTimer.innerHTML = sec;
  }
  if (sec <= 0) {
    $("#myBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#myBtn").removeClass().addClass("btnEnable");
    $("#myTimer").fadeTo(2500, 0);
    myBtn.innerHTML = "Click Me!";
    return;
  }
  sec -= 1;
  window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}
```

which creates button like this.
[image: image of button]

but i cant specify date and time for enabling button. any idea about that?

Comment: use moment.js and moment timezone.js. That will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Button during certain day & time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002059/enable-button-during-certain-day-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put setInterval to check continue like

```
setInterval(function(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();

   if ( dd == Date.parse ("your date") ) {
       // enable your button
   } 
}, 3000);
```